# How to create a CSV file by removing zeros from Matlab Array

Tags: matlab, file, csv

I am having a Matlab Array:
A = [ 1 2 0 0 0; 7 8 9 1 2; 4 5 6 0 0 ]

I need to write this array into a CSV file in the following format:
1 2 \n 
7 8 9 1 2 \n 
4 5 6

Which means I need to remove the zeros while writing the CSV file. Is there any other function other than dlmwrite() which can create such a CSV file by removing the zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach with [`fprintf`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) -

```
output_file = 'results.txt';    %// output text filename
fid = fopen(output_file, 'w');  %// open file for writing
for k = 1:size(A,1)             %// run for-loop for all rows

    %// For each row select the non zero elements and then create a 
    %// non-trailing string version of it and write to each line of output file
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n',num2str(nonzeros(A(k,:))')); %//'
end
fclose(fid);                    %// close the file after writing
```

Verify -

```
>> type results.txt

1  2
7  8  9  1  2
4  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format you're looking for is simply a list of the non-zero elements of `A`, just removed them before writing:

```
Ano0 = A(A ~= 0);
dlmwrite('file.csv',Ano0 ,',');
```

---

For line breaks between the rows, you can loop through the rows of `A` like

```
maskNo0 = A~=0;
for k = 1:size(A,1)
    dlmwrite('file.csv',A(k,maskNo0),'-append');
end
```

Comment: I need to create separate csv files for all the generated arrays from my Matlab code. This means, the '-append' will not work. It is defintely correct way to solve the problem. But, in my scenario, I need to create a new csv file all over again for every matrix which is encountered. I suppose I have to create a blank file before, and then go on appending it with elements.

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, `dlmwrite` will create it automatically.  So you should be able to put the above code into a loop with a varying file name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str = mat2str(A);                 %// this gives [1 2 0 0 0;7 8 9 1 2;4 5 6 0 0]
str([1 end]) = [];                %// remove brackets
str = regexprep(str,' 0','');     %// remove zeros with their spaces
str = regexprep(str,';','\\n ');  %// change semicolons to line-feeds
fid = fopen('filename.csv','w');  %// open file for writing
fwrite(fid,str);                  %// write contents to file
fclose(fid);                      %// close file
```